# Starting Javascript intervals nonsynchronously and stop each after three runs

Tags: javascript, loops, counter, setinterval

I have a function for letting blink a OpenLayer marker three times. The simplified version which only shows console messages:

```
function blink_three_times(layername){
var x = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
        blink_in = setInterval(function() {
            x = x+1;
            if ( x === 3) {clearInterval(blink_in)};
            console.log(layername + ' is visible');
        }, 500);
    }, 250);

    blink_out = setInterval(function() {
        if (x === 2) {clearInterval(blink_out)};
        console.log(layername + ' is invisible');    
    }, 500);
};
```

It works fine, but if it is started multiple times before one has finished, the counter (x) exceeds 3 and the interval does not stop. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have funcions `blink_in` & `blink_out` in global scope. When you are calling it second time it overwrites the definitions of functions.

Define them using var to make them local.

```
var blink_in = setInterval(function() {..})
```

and

```
var blink_out = setInterval(function() {..})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/74/)

Answer (score 1):

Your variables blink_in and blink_out are global ones so if you call the function multiple times they will override it and therefore cannot stop the interval properly.

Use them in your function scope by definining them with "var" in order to avoid the problem (see http://jsfiddle.net/cb0h8tst/)

```
function blink_three_times(layername){
    var x = 0;
    var blink_in, blink_out;
    setTimeout(function() {
        blink_in = setInterval(function() {
            x = x+1;
            if ( x === 3) {clearInterval(blink_in)};
            console.log(layername + ' is visible');
        }, 500);
    }, 250);
    blink_out = setInterval(function() {
        if (x === 2) {clearInterval(blink_out)};
        console.log(layername + ' is invisible');    
    }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last update question,

you could also make a more dynamic to keep track of the layers that are actually being blinked, a possible example

```
function Blinker(opt) {
    var ts = {};

    this.elementId = opt ? opt.elementId : undefined;
    this.runs = (opt ? opt.runs : 3) || 3;
    this.completed = (opt ? opt.completed : function() { }) || function() { };

    this.start = function(arg) {
        var timestamp = arg || this.elementId, that = this;
        if (typeof ts[timestamp] !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('Cannot run multiple times on same layer');
            return;
        }
        ts[timestamp] = {
            timestamp: timestamp,
            count: 0, 
            element: document.getElementById(arg || this.elementId),
            controller: this
        };
        setTimeout(function() {
            ts[timestamp].showInterval = setInterval(that.setVisibility.bind(ts[timestamp], true), 500);
        }, 250);
        ts[timestamp].hideInterval = setInterval(this.setVisibility.bind(ts[timestamp], false), 500);
    };

    this.setVisibility = function(visible) {
        this.element.style.visibility = visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        this.element.style.display = visible ? 'inherit' : 'none';
        if (visible) {
            this.count++;
        }
        if (!visible && this.count === 2)
        {
            clearInterval(this.hideInterval);
        }
        if (visible && this.count === 3)
        {
            clearInterval(this.showInterval);
            this.controller.completed.apply(this.controller, [this.element.id]);
            delete ts[this.timestamp];
        }
    };
}

var blinker = new Blinker({
    elementId: 'blinker',
    runs: 3,
    completed: function(elementId) {
        var log = document.getElementById('log');
        log.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + elementId + '</strong> has finished blinking</p>';
    }
});
```

you could find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/q70w0kpx/